# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in functions.php on line 674

Tags: php, invalid-argument

i tried to go online after finishing the website but a error occurs 
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in functions.php on line 674

```
foreach ( $one_array_font as $font => $variants ) {
    $font = str_replace(' ', '+', $font);
    $variants = implode(',', array_values($variants['variant']) );
    $all_final_fonts[] = $font.':'.$variants;
}

$gfont = implode('|', $all_final_fonts); /* <-- This line fails */

wp_enqueue_style( 'zn_all_g_fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$gfont.''.$subset);

if ( $data['zn_main_style'] == 'dark' ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('zn-dark-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/dark-theme.css',array() ,false,'all');
}

if ( !empty ( $data['g_fonts_subset'] ) ) {
   $subset = '&subset='.str_replace( ' ' , '' , $data['g_fonts_subset']);
}
```

Comment: what's line 674? i'm not a wizard

Comment: there is code   $gfont = implode('|', $all_final_fonts); whts wrong with it?

Comment: var_dump($all_final_fonts) please .

Comment: try to declare `$all_final_fonts = array();` outside loop

Comment: I think you should declare your $all_final_fonts array before the "foreach" loop, so that if $one_array_loop is empty, it will not crash ($all_final_fonts being undefined)

Answer (score 2):

Not really enough info in the question, but this is what I think is happening:

- Firstly, `$one_array_font` is empty.
- This means that the `foreach()` loop is never run.
- This means that the line `$all_final_fonts[] = $font.':'.$variants;` is never run.
- I'm guessing that `$all_final_fonts` was not defined earlier. Therefore it is still undefined when the code gets to the `implode`.
- The `implode()` fails because it requires the input field to be an array, but you've given it an undefined variable.

**Solution**

Ensure that `$all_final_fonts` is defined regardless, by adding the following line before the `foreach()` loop:

```
$all_final_fonts = array();
```

This will initialise the variable as an array, so that `implode()` won't complain about it if you don't have any data.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that warning because $all_final_fonts is not an array.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

regards